# Custom XML in Word documents

Tags: xml, ms-word, ms-office

Microsoft lost another [patent lawsuit](http://blogs.zdnet.com/Bott/?p=1600) (see also [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/978951)) and I feel the pain too. I relied on the [pink tags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa212889%28office.11%29.aspx) to have some attributes associated with text spans in a word documents. Such attributes were saved in the xml as custom tags.

Now, as soon as my customer upgrades Office suite they will loose the pink tags. Can you think of what features can I use in MS Word to re-implement the same functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends on your Word version. In Word 2003 you might want to have a look at the Bookmark feature, from Word 2007 on you could also investigate Content Controls/Custom XML.

Comment: CustomXML as in the lawsuit MS lost?

Comment: The system was written for 2003, but the development of the replacement will have to relay on the 2007/2010

Comment: @mfeingold: No, 2007 brings a different concept how to add a custom XML document as a separate document part to the OpenXML package. This kind of XML is not affected.